# java-image processing

Tags: java, image, image-processing

what is the value returned when we perform

> image[i]>>18 & 0x30, image[i]>>12 & 0xc, image[i]>>6 & 0x3

to an image

Comment: "this code is part of my project.but i can't understand it" - candidate for best title on SO

Comment: if it is a part of your project then why can't you understand it (if you have written or copied it?) :)

Comment: Is this copied from LocalColorHistogram.java or GlobalColorHistogram.java ?

Comment: this is my first project.i really could use some help.i google d it million times but couldn't get any results

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the value of k ?i can't understand it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599003/what-is-the-value-of-k-i-cant-understand-it)

Comment: pradeep:no one is helping me.k.

Comment: @renjith737 You can't expect to google every line of code, sometimes you need to read what is there and understand it i.e. because not all code is copies of code other people have written.

Comment: yep.this code is to perform LocalColorHistogram and GlobalColorHistogram.i am trying to implement it.

Comment: @renjith737, without correct context, it would be difficult for anyone to help right? at-least put your context, where it is executing, etc

Comment: i read many articles etc.... but none of them say how to get the histograms from an image.

Comment: @RenoJones : i am trying to implement a CBIR.the algorithms used are LocalColorHistogram and GlobalColorHistogram.this is part of a code i couldn't understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is building a number which contains the 6th, 7th, 14th, 15th, 22nd and 23rd bits from the original image's colour. i.e. it is producing a crude 6-bit colour from a 24-bit colour.

e.g.

```
000000000rrrrrrrrrggggggggbbbbbbbb
```

becomes the top bits of

```
rrbbgg
```